# Calculating sum of a column in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this code I want to show array of numbers using Javascript, what I what is when refreshing the page 10 random numbers will will be shown, and dividing the 10 numbers into two columns, in a way to obtain 5 numbers in a column, and ending up by having the sum of each column separately.

Here is my code, in which I am not able to divide numbers into two column and calculate the sum.

```
<div id="display">
    <script language = "javascript">
    var sum=0;
    rnums = new Array(10);
    rnums2 = new Array(10);
    for (i = 1; i< 10; i++)
    {
    rnums[i]=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    rnums2[i]=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    var sum = rnums[i]+""+rnums2[i];
    document.write(rnums[i]+""+rnums2[i]+" ");
    }
    document.write("<br>" + "The total is " + sum);
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: `var sum = rnums[i]+""+rnums2[i];` ? shouldn't it be `var sum = rnums[i]+rnums2[i];`

Comment: No, because it is a rolling dice small game, which should shows on each time and on each dice a number between 1 and 6, and mixing the result of the dice one with dice two.